# How to write a string and a numpy array in a file?

Tags: python, numpy

I am computing features for images read from a directory and I want to write the image path and the corresponding features in a file, separated by spaces. The output is desired in this fashion

```
/path/to/img1.jpg 1 0 0 1 3.5 0.2 0
/path/to/img2.jpg 0 0 0.5 2.1 0 0.7
...
```

Following is part of my code

```
features.open('file.txt', 'w')
for fname in fnmatch.filter(fileList, '*.jpg'):
    image = '/path/to/image'
    # All the operations are here
    myarray = [......] # array of dimensions 512x512
    myarray.reshape(1, 512*512) # Reshape to make it a row vector
    features.write(image + ' '.join(str(myarray)))
features.write('\n')
features.close()
```

But the output is coming as

```
/path/to/img1.jpg[[0 0 1.0 2 3]]
/path/to/img2.jpg[[1.2 0 1.0 2 0.3]]
```

Comment: Can you define " not properly?" Not at all? How does the output look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem lies in the following statement:

```
>>> ' '.join(str(np.array([1,2,3])))
'[ 1   2   3 ]'
```

You first turn the array into a string format

```
>>> str(np.array([1,2,3]))
'[1 2 3]'
```

and then join the elements of the string (individual characters) with spaces in between.

---

Instead, you need to turn the individual elements of the numpy array into a list of strings, for example by using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map).

```
>>> map(str, np.array([1,2,3]))
['1', '2', '3']
```

Only then should you join the elements of the resulting list of strings:

```
>>> ' '.join(map(str, np.array([1,2,3])))
'1 2 3'
```

---

The next problem will come from the fact that the numpy array you have is actually two-dimensional:

```
>>> map(str, np.array([[1,2,3]]))
['[1 2 3]']
```

This is simple to solve, since you've already turned it into a single row using `reshape`. So, just apply `map` to the first row:

```
>>> ' '.join(map(str, np.array([[1,2,3]])[0]))
'1 2 3'
```